# How to understand request object?

Tags: express, http

In my expresjs code, if I print an incoming request from app.js...

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req);
    ...
```

I can see some headers that I expect, such as

```
url: '/'
method: 'GET'
```

But there are a surprising number of others included, such as

```
_readableState:
_events:
socket:
```

In mdn these do not appear in the list of http headers.  Nor do they appear in Request interface properties.

Then what am I looking at? Can someone please point me towards a resource to help me understand what these values are used for?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#class-httpclientrequest

Comment: @robertklep - That's not the right object for `req` in Express.  See my answer below.

Comment: @jfriend00 but the page is a resource to help them understand what the values are used for ;D

Comment: @robertklep - You specifically liinked to a class that is not what Express uses the `req` object.  That class if for making an outgoing request with `http.request()`, not when Express receives an incoming request.

Comment: @jfriend00 uhm oops, you're absolutely right, apologies (coffee hasn't kicked in yet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request object is an Express-customized version of `http.IncomingMessage` as described in the nodejs doc [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#class-httpincomingmessage).

At it's core, it is a combination of properties from the incoming request (such as incoming headers) and a [stream.readable](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#class-streamreadable) that represents the incoming data from the http request.

If the request is a GET, then there is typically no body to that request and the headers of the request have already been read from the incoming stream (by the underlying http library) and parsed and are stored in the `req` object as properties that you can read about [here](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req) in the Express doc and [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#class-httpincomingmessage) in the http library doc.

If the request is something with a body such as a PUT or POST, then the `req` object represents the TCP stream where the body data can be read from either by your custom request handler or by middleware such as `express.json()` or `multer` or other middleware designed to handle specific types of http bodies.

Properties such as `_readableState` are part of the incoming stream in `req`.

Properties such as `method` are part of the `http.incomingMessage` in `req`.

Properties such as `socket` are the underlying TCP socket that the http request arrived on and is used by the stream to read the body from the stream and to close the request when done reading.

`req` is essentially a blend or mixin of several classes giving it these various behaviors all in one object.

Comment: Thank you!  This explanation, and those links, are very helpful!